# Android emulator problems

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My Android emulator is so slow it doesn't actually display any my Android work!I've left it for an hour and came back to find nothing. I'd really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: It can sometimes be a bit slow. Make sure that the device is not locked when you go to launch the application or it will sit there indefinitely. Does it function without any issues on a real device?

Comment: what computer are you using, and which avd ?

Comment: If you can, use a physical device for testing. I've found the emulator is unusable on my 5 year old laptop when targetting anything later than 2.2.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't own any android devices, my laptop is only a few months old, its an HP Pavilion g6 with w8

Comment: If you are targetting older versions of Android, make AVDs that are older. These will run better.

Comment: AVD supports platform 4.2 API level level 17, however I don't think its the AVD because I've tried so many and still encountered the same problem

Comment: Are you running as Admin or a user in Windows?

Comment: I'm running as a user

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slow Android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

Comment: Not all Android emulators are supposed to work up to the mark. There are choices like BlueStacks and BlueStacks 2, but because of the surveys, they also suck. You can give a try to Andy OS though http://techappspc.com/how-to-run-apps-for-pc-via-andy-os/

Answer (score 0):

May be problem with your Memory...try to edit AVD just increase or decrease the RAM size..try to refer this link...[here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the memory. I would also recommend using a "common" AVD. Similar to here:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/

If that doesn't work i would strongly recommend getting an android device. There are a lot of cheap ones (especially from China).

But this is also a repeat question, see here:

[Is there any way to reduce the boot up time of Android Emulator provided with android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384706/is-there-any-way-to-reduce-the-boot-up-time-of-android-emulator-provided-with-an)

Answer (score 0):

Probably your computer is a little bit slow for the settings.

I noticed that high-resolution emulator consumes a lot of resources. So basically run it with 340-400 resolution, works much faster. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Genymotion. You can download a version for Windows/Mac OS X/Linux after registering. A plugin for Eclipse is also avaliable.

i give you link [Genymotion Emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/) please download and setup.

as per my experience Genymotion Vertual device is faster then android emulator.